# Force group for new files in NFSv4 ACLs

Tags: permissions, freebsd, acl

I have a folder, `/srv/share`, which I'd like to share between a few users who share a non-primary group (`share`). I'd like to force that any file and/or directory moved or created into `/srv/share` are owned by the `share` group. I'm using FreeBSD 11 and the share is on a ZFS volume.

As of now, this *almost* works - I'm using `setgid` on the folder (which is already owned by `share`), and if I create a subdirectory it is owned by the correct group. However,  if an application running as a user who is member of the `share` group moves files in a directory into `/srv/share`, the files are owned by the application user's group.

How should I setup this? I'm lost and two evenings of googling has given me almost nothing.

Comment: Why do you need to force group ownership if you can directly grant it access via ACLs?

Comment: The volume is shared over network and it makes it easier to setup accounts, at least from what I've learned so far.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have a freebsd console available to me atm, but this appears to work on Mac OS X):

> chown :share /srv/share
>
> chmod g+s /srv/share

`mv` within the same mounted filesystem normally retains the ownership and permissions as the file existed in its origin location. However, across mounted filesystems I would expect the behavior to look more like `cp` followed by `unlink`. Therefore, I believe the `g+s` should have the required behavior.